# grep loop: I'm using each line of one file as query to find matches another file. Why is my output inconsistent?

Tags: grep, for

I have one file `query_ids` with several lines such as:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

I'm using `grep idx` to find matches of the id in `my_file`.
I redirect these matches to a new `matches` file.
I'm also using `grep` with option `-v` to obtain all mismatches which I redirect to a `mismatches` file. I'm using this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in $(cat query_ids)
do 
    # saving matches 
    grep "$i" my_file >> matches
    # saving mismatches
    grep -v "$i" my_file >> missing
done
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong: 
When manually searching some ids from the `missing` file in `my_file` I find that they exist.
Even though the `missing` file should only contain ids from the file `query_ids` that were NOT found in `my_file` I do find matches.

So when picking some random id let's say id3 by doing `grep id3 missing` and `grep id3 my_file` both return a match. <br>

Why is my code assigning id3 to `mismatches` file?

1. I tried removing the quotes around `$i` but it did not change the result.
2. I also tried `echo "$i"` to be sure that the id's are actually looped.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is that you get one ID, say `id1`, and then you extract all lines matching that ID into `matches`.  Then you extract all lines *not* matching that into `missing`.

For the next ID, `id2`, you then add the lines matching that ID to `matches`, and the lines not matching `id2` to `missing`.

Now, `missing` contains all lines not containing `id1`, then all lines not containing `id2`.  Note that a line containing `id1` that does not contain `id2` would be in `missing` from that second iteration of your loop.

Instead, consider all IDs at once:

```bsh
grep -f query_ids -Fw    my_file >matches
grep -f query_ids -Fw -v my_file >missing
```

Here, I'm  providing `grep` with patterns from `query_ids` using `-f`.  I'm asking `grep` to treat the lines in `query_ids` as query strings (`-F`, i.e. not regular expressions), and to match these in `my_file` as whole words (`-w`, so that `id2` does not match e.g. `id23`).

The first command would extract all lines that contain any of the IDs.  The second command would extract all lines that contain none of the IDs.

There is no need for a loop of any kind here.